# How to concatenate two TextStyle?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to concat two TextStyle like react or react-native.

```
    style={[styles.firstStyle, styles.secondStyle]}
```

but i don't know how to do this in flutter.
How to result like below?

```
    TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontFamily: CUSTOM)
```

This concatenate with:

```
    TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 17)
```

result is below.

```
    TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontFamily: CUSTOM, fontSize: 17)
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use the [merge method](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/TextStyle/merge.html).

```
var firstStyle = TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontFamily: CUSTOM);
var secondStyle = TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 17);

var mergedStyle = firstStyle.merge(secondStyle);
```